# how to resolve 'DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.'?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My goal is to export data to a pdf file using crystal report and entity framework but unfortunately, I have been receiving this error message when I try to run my code.

> 'System.NotSupportedException: 'DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.'

Can anyone please kindly assist me?

This is what I have tried so far on my controller side

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using Final_INF271.Reports;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public ActionResult Export()
{
    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
    rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/OutstandingOrders.rpt")));
    rd.SetDataSource(db.ProductOrder.Select(p => new
    {
        p.OrderID,
        p.Date,
        p.SupplierID,
        p.CostPrice,
        p.Quantity
    }).ToList());
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream
        (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "OutstandingOrders");
}
```

Included is my ProductOrder

```
namespace Final_INF271.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ProductOrder
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SupplierID { get; set; }
        public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CostPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

below is a picture of Data set and error message

[image]

Comment: Please include your model class of `ProductOrder`, there's should be some nullable properties which causing the problem.

Comment: I have included my model class ProductOrder

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports' `SetDataSource()` method creates `DataColumn` supplied by list of `ProductOrder`, and then trying to build `DataColumn` instances that has nullable type, which is not supported.

You should either create a viewmodel class which has properties with same base types but without nullable types present, then project the result with that class as data source:

```
// Viewmodel
public class ProductOrderVM
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

// Controller action
rd.SetDataSource(db.ProductOrder.Select(p => new ProductOrderVM
{
    OrderID = p.OrderID,
    Date = p.Date.GetValueOrDefault(),
    SupplierID = p.SupplierID.GetValueOrDefault(),
    CostPrice = p.CostPrice.GetValueOrDefault(),
    Quantity = p.Quantity.GetValueOrDefault()
}).ToList());
```

Or use null coalescing/ternary operator to assign default values according to their base type if the nullable properties have null value:

```
rd.SetDataSource(db.ProductOrder.Select(p => new
{
    OrderID = p.OrderID,

    // with ternary operator
    Date = p.Date == null ? DateTime.MinValue : p.Date, // or DateTime.Now as default value

    // with null-coalescing operator
    SupplierID = p.SupplierID ?? 0,
    CostPrice = p.CostPrice ?? 0,
    Quantity = p.Quantity ?? 0
}).ToList());
```

Comment: how to use these operators in where clause ?